# VS Code - Sync with VPS : Add file / Rename / Delete

Tags: visual-studio-code

I start with VS Code. But I develop on VPS Debian, not in local on my Windows.

I search plugin SFTP which does :

- -when with VS Code I create a new file, that it automatically upload it to my VPS

  -when with VS Code I delete a file, it also removes    it automatically on my VPS

  -when with VS Code I rename a file,    that it also renames it automatically on my VPS

  -and a project, I    upload it on 2 VPS, so I need to easily change SFTP ID

Please, Do you know if there is a plugin that works (for real)?

I searched all day, I found none that works for real.

the one that comes closest to what I want is liximomo sftp, but does not work well ... : https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/701

Thak you very much.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have same problem, I get used to develop project on my server. I was previously using Netbeans, which does all automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to move from netbeans to vsCode and ran into the same problem: when I eg. rename a file in netbeans it is renamed on the server too.

The only solution for the problem other than coding with Netbeans seems to be using both. Netbeans happily syncs files which are changed by other programs - but it must run all the time.

Maybe there is an other solution with a smaller sync-program but I did not look into it more deeply because I may abandon vsCode because of this and because it does not work very well with php and I write more php than javascript and css.

eg. with the following code:

```
require_once 'include/connect.inc.php';
$db_->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id>0");
```

the problem is that the system does not know, that $db_ is a mysqli-class, when declared in an include file - the same goes for every class - so there is no autocompletion and I often create the object in the include-file